# Codevision generate `.ASM` output

Tags: c, assembly, hex, atmega16

CodevisionAVR gets a `.c` file and generates `.hex` and `.o` outputs.

Is it possible to generate `.asm` file out of it too?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [CodeVisionAVR tutorial](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ee476/codevisionC/Tutorial.PDF), when you press the **Compile** or **Make** buttons on the toolbar, an `.asm` file should be generated from your `.c` files, e.g. `tutor1.asm` should be generated from `tutor1.c`.

Maybe try using a "find in files" tool to look for `.asm` files after issuing Make from the IDE?